# Change list-style-type image depending on file extension?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying to change the list-style-image depending on what the file extension is on my links within an iframe. The code below is what I have so far, and that applies the pdf icon to ALL the 's within the iframe, not just the ones that are pdf's. What am I doing wrong here? Hopefully you can help!

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$( "iframe#mframe" ).load(function () {
    if($('a[href$=".pdf"]')) {
        $('iframe#mframe').contents().find( "li" ).css("list-style-image" , "url('/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/pdf_icon.gif')" );
    }
    else if ($('a[href$=".docx"]')) {
        $('iframe#mframe').contents().find( "li" ).css("list-style-image" , "url('/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/docx_icon.png')" );
    }
    else if ($('a[href$=".wmv"]')) {
        $('iframe#mframe').contents().find( "li" ).css("list-style-image" , "url('/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/wmv_icon.png')" );
    }
});
```

});

Thanks guys, always appreciative of your help!

Edit: Although I am using Ecropolis' answer, I worked out another way of going about it:

```
        $('iframe#mframe').contents().find( 'li a[href*=".pdf"]' ).before('<img src="/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/pdf_icon.gif" />');
```

And it works flawlessly, aside from the fact it wouldn't be the most semantic way of going about it if I had hundreds of file types in these folders! Nonetheless, my question has been answered, and for that, I thank all who got involved ever so much! All the best!

Comment: Wonderful, what does your relevant HTML look like exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Reuse the string for file type to path to the correct image. Either way I think the .each() function is what you need to solve the problem. You have if statements and your selectors inside of each one will always find the same elements.

```
$( "iframe#mframe a" ).each(function( index ) {
  var type = $(this).attr('src').slice( -3 );
  $(this).css("list-style-image" , "url('/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/"+type+"_icon.gif')" );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That worked nicely, and much more semantic! I did find another way to go about it, but a lot less semantic than yours, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer an alternative approach:

```
$('iframe#mframe li').css('list-style-image', function(){
    return "url('/wp-content/themes/mintranet/img/icons/" + $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('.').pop() + "_icon.gif')"
});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: Thank you for your input! It's muchly appreciated!